# Aliasing a class method in definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to make a typing definition file for Mootools, namely the aliasing of `$('myid')` for `document.id('myid')`. I made a interface for `Document`, which is

```
interface Document {
  id(el: string): Element;
  ...
}
```

In JQuery.d.ts `$` is aliasing the JQuery object, how can I alias an object method?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'aliasing' is performed by the *implementation*.

In the *definition*, simply declare the function you want to expose, for example

```
declare/export function $(el: string): Element;
```

Comment: Aliasing is because Element has a host of methods defined, so I was looking for a way to dry `$` up and replicate all the methods defined for Element...